# How to program an STM32 MCU on a custom PCB

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pcb-design, stm32, embedded

I am designing a PCB using an STM32 MCU to control a motor. My main concern is being able to use STM32CUBE IDE or the Arduino IDE to program the board. I don't want to spend a lot of money on a JTAG board or on the ST-Link since it would double my project costs. My plan was to use this USB-UART converter to program the STM32 through its UART pins. (https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ftdi-future-technology-devices-international-ltd/FT231XS-R/3029139)

I would then connect that to a USB header that I could plug into my PC with.

Are there any glaring issues with this approach? I'm not concerned about debugging since the software is very simple and an oscilloscope will tell me what I need to know.

Comment: You never said which STM32 model. Depending on model, it might support flashing via USB directly. Also, a genuine ST-Link is only about 20 USD or 20 EUR. Because it allows you to debug over JTAG and SWD, it is well worth having one when developing the firmware.

Comment: The ST-Link will save you a lot of time.  Is your time really that cheap?

Comment: As the firmware aspect of it is not very involved. There is little to no debugging that I foresee with this project. I guess I can buy the STlink, I am just trying to keep my BOM as small as I can

Comment: The ST-Link can be external to your board and reused from board to board (and project to project).  I don't understand why you would include it on your BOM.  You should only need to add a Cortex debug connector to your BOM, for connecting the ST-Link to the board.  In your USB-UART design, would you be putting the FTDI chip and a USB connector on your board?  Doesn't that result in a larger BOM?